# XSLT: How to remove elements of a resulting result tree fragment while copying?

Tags: xslt

My goal is to extract the contents of the SOAP body, f.e. the `ElementsToExtract` node - but the node name can basically be arbitrary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <MessageId>52DF2371-4094-4408-A3EA-42D73FD1B7A3</MessageId>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ElementsToExtract>
        ...
        <RemoveMe>...</RemoveMe>
        <RemoveMeAlso>...</RemoveMeAlso>
        ...
    </ElementsToExtract>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

While I'm extracting the contents, I want to get rid of two elements that all my source documents have in common - say `RemoveMe` and `RemoveMeAlso`. As there's a chance that the deeper nested nodes may be called the same, they must only be stripped from the layer below the `ElementsToExtract` node. How would I formulate that expression?

Here's what I did up to now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="soap exsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="SoapHeaderContents" select="exsl:node-set(soap:Envelope/soap:Header/*)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="SoapBodyContents" select="exsl:node-set(soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$SoapBodyContents"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- This is global, how to restrict to the ElementsToExtract element? -->
  <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'RemoveMe']"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()[name() = 'RemoveMeAlso']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also played with the `node-set()` function, having read that one can not modify result tree fragments (they're only text nodes?), but I don't quite understand how to address the resulting nodes of that set. So the nodes weren't removed:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$SoapBodyContents"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$SoapBodyContents/RemoveMe" mode="m1"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="StripRemoveMe" match="RemoveMe" mode="m1"/>
```

I also read some parts of the specification, but to no avail. I'm lost for clues. Can someone direct me to the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
exclude-result-prefixes="soap">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- skip soap wrappers -->
<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Body/ElementsToExtract"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove unwanted elements -->
<xsl:template match="ElementsToExtract/RemoveMe | ElementsToExtract/RemoveMeAlso"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

In the (unlikely) case you don't know the name of the `ElementsToExtract` element, you could use:

```
<!-- skip soap wrappers -->
<xsl:template match="/soap:Envelope">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Body/*"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove unwanted elements -->
<xsl:template match="soap:Body/*/RemoveMe | soap:Body/*/RemoveMeAlso"/>
```

Comment: The unlikely case mattered to me ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some quick thoughts.

- You create variables for storing the SOAP header and body.  These are already in the input document, so it makes more sense to just write templates that match these.
- Although you create a variable for the SOAP header, you never use it anywhere.
- If you try to apply templates in succession, as in your sample XSL code, you will get all the output nodes from the first `apply-templates`, and then all the output nodes from the next `apply-templates`.  If these nodes are meant to be interleaved in any way, this approach will not produce viable output.

Here's a revised version of your sample input XML, adding in a couple elements that we want to keep.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <MessageId>52DF2371-4094-4408-A3EA-42D73FD1B7A3</MessageId>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ElementsToExtract>
        <KeepMe>This text will persist in the output.</KeepMe>
        <RemoveMe>This is text that will be removed.</RemoveMe>
        <RemoveMeAlso>This will also vanish from the output.</RemoveMeAlso>
        <OtherElementToKeep>And this one will also be kept.</OtherElementToKeep>
    </ElementsToExtract>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's what we'd want as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ElementsToExtract>
    <KeepMe>This text will persist in the output.</KeepMe>
    <OtherElementToKeep>And this one will also be kept.</OtherElementToKeep>
</ElementsToExtract>
```

This XSL 1.0 code will do the job.  I'm guessing from your post that you're not familiar with XSL processing flow, so I've added comments to help explain what's going on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    version="1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="soap">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- The `/` matches the _logical root_ of the input file.  This is 
        basically equivalent to the start of the file, NOT the first element.
        This is a common place to start processing in XSL. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- We just apply templates.  In your case, we know already that
            we DON'T want to process everything: we want to leave certain
            things out, including a lot of the outermost elements.  So
            we specify what to target in the `select` statement. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ElementsToExtract"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This is the "identity" template, so called because it 
        just copies over applicable matches identically. 
        A template with a more-specific match statement takes
        precedence. -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Here, we specify exactly those elements that are in the 
        processing flow, and that we want to exclude from the
        output.  Since `soap:Header` etc. are NOT in the processing
        flow (their element trees were never included in a preceding 
        call to `apply-templates`), we don't need to worry about those. -->
    <xsl:template match="RemoveMe | RemoveMeAlso"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the outermost element in the output is `ElementsToExtract`.  This element will include the `xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"` namespace declaration, even though this namespace isn't used in any of the output elements (at least, for this small sample input XML).

If you can use XSL 2.0+ and you want to remove this namespace from the output, you could add the `copy-namespaces="no"` attribute to the `<xsl:copy>` element.

Comment: Thank you Eiríkr. I had to choose Michael's answer for the obscure case where I don't know the element, but your solution is also fine. Thanks for the effort of explaining things :-)

Comment: @RenéSchindhelm, I'm curious -- from your description, it's unclear.  is it just that you need to extract everything under `soap:Body`, without copying the `soap:Body` element itself?  If so, just replace `ElementsToExtract` in my code above with `*`.  The `*` stands for "anything".